# Access violation when using OpenSSL's HMAC

Tags: c, openssl, hmac

I'm trying to do an HMAC-SHA512 on some data using OpenSSL.  I get an "`Exception thrown at 0x... (libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x...`" error when executing the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  uint8_t* data[] = { 0x14, 0xf7, 0xbd, 0x95, 0x57, 0x9a, 0x7e, 0xa1, 0x5c, 0xf7, 0x27, 0x91, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x58, 0x01, 0xa3, 0x12, 0x17, 0x54, 0x0b, 0x2e, 0xb4, 0xc5, 0xb1, 0xeb, 0xab, 0xe0, 0x43, 0x9b, 0x8e, 0x1f, 0x39, 0x7d, 0x85, 0x1a, 0x3a, 0x4b, 0x9c, 0xf4, 0xbf, 0x31, 0x55, 0x72, 0x41, 0xf5, 0xdb, 0xcb, 0xb3, 0xa6, 0xb5, 0xb8, 0x82, 0xe5, 0xef, 0x18, 0x72, 0xa0, 0x59, 0x08, 0x9b, 0xfa, 0x17, 0xa3 };
  uint8_t* key = "some_rand_pw";
  uint8_t* result = malloc(64);
  memset(result, 0, 64);
  HMAC(EVP_sha512(), key, 12, data, 64, result, (unsigned int)64); //ERROR
}
```

I would use `uint8_t* result = HMAC(EVP_sha512(), key, 12, data, 64, NULL, NULL)`, but it isn't thread safe, and this will be a multithreaded program.  Anyone have any idea what I did wrong here?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with 64-bit OpenSSL pre-built for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. `data` must be an array of `uint8`, but you declared it as an array of pointers to `uint8`.

Furthermore the last parameter of `HMAC` must be a *pointer* to `unsigned int` but you provided an `unsigned int`, that's the reason for the crash.

Your compiler should have warned you. Compile with `-Wall`.

Corrected (untested) code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  uint8_t data[] = { 0x14, 0xf7, 0xbd, 0x95, 0x57, 0x9a, 0x7e, 0xa1, 0x5c, 0xf7, 0x27, 0x91, 0x0d, 0x61, 0x58, 0x01, 0xa3, 0x12, 0x17, 0x54, 0x0b, 0x2e, 0xb4, 0xc5, 0xb1, 0xeb, 0xab, 0xe0, 0x43, 0x9b, 0x8e, 0x1f, 0x39, 0x7d, 0x85, 0x1a, 0x3a, 0x4b, 0x9c, 0xf4, 0xbf, 0x31, 0x55, 0x72, 0x41, 0xf5, 0xdb, 0xcb, 0xb3, 0xa6, 0xb5, 0xb8, 0x82, 0xe5, 0xef, 0x18, 0x72, 0xa0, 0x59, 0x08, 0x9b, 0xfa, 0x17, 0xa3 };
  uint8_t* key = "some_rand_pw";
  uint8_t* result = malloc(64);
  unsigned int len;
  memset(result, 0, 64);
  HMAC(EVP_sha512(), key, 12, data, 64, result, &len);
}
```

There is still room for improvement though.